# Authenticating with Netatmo API using MSAL.NET results in "Error: ClientId is not a GUID."

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am writing a Windows app that will retrieve weather station readings from Netatmo.
The app needs to authenticate with Netatmo API (authentication code grant), and I am trying to use MSAL's `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` for this.

The client Id provided by Netatmo's app registration is a 24 character string, while MSAL seams to accept only string that can be parsed into a GUID. Therefore, the builder throws a MsalClientException with message: "Error: ClientId is not a GUID.".

```
var publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
   .Create("8543a5684dbe6325b15bcc4b")
   .WithAuthority("https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2")
   .Build();
```

According to OAuth2 ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2)) the client Id is not required to be a GUID.

So the question is, is their a work-around for this odd requirement in MSAL, or should I use a different authentication client?
The app already uses MSAL to authenticate with outlook.office.com, therefore that was my first choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft identity platform (aka Azure AD) exclusively uses GUIDs for its client IDs. Since MSAL is a library designed specifically for interacting with this, and officially does not support other identity providers, they've decided to enforce this restriction in the library itself. Here's [a longstanding issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1538) on their GitHub repo.

In the meantime, you would probably have to use a different library, or roll your own.